# Error using module in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular.js and have a problem. Please help me resolve it.
I have created a simple screen using a controller and a module in my example.
But it doesnt work. I have presented the example as follows :

My html file is :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ayan">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hotel_listing_angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in htlList"> 
        {{ contact.name }} 
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my js file is as follows :-

```
var ayan=angular.module('ayan',[]);
ayan.controller('myController',function ($scope) {

    $scope.htlList = [
                   {name:"Picard", description:"Captain"},
                   {name:"Santosh", description:"Programmer"},
                   {name:"Amit", description:"Manager"}
                   ];

});
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you checked for any javascript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="hotel_listing_angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

before calling

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="hotel_listing_angular.js"></script>
```